# Getting iso from mirror sites

Tags: linux

I am a little confused with all the files on the mirror site. Like when I went to mirror site of damn small linux, there were lot of files and directories and I couldn't get through all of them.
How to find iso in these files?

Comment: Here http://distro.ibiblio.org/damnsmall/current/ for example.

Comment: there are a lot of isos. So, which one to choose? I know according to user preference but what the tags mean like current, initrd, embedded?

Comment: There's a reason why one of the files is called [`1-readme_first.txt`](http://distro.ibiblio.org/damnsmall/current/1-readme_first.txt).

Comment: Oh, didn't see it. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally there is a folder for your architecture, and you go to that. Inside it there will probably be one called “current”, or it could be that was the first folder. The ISOs are not usually at the end of the directory tree, you just have to find the right folder. Usually mirror sites don’t have that many other files as long as you don’t click on source directories or anything. Just look for your architecture and then a folder labeled with the latest version. There usually isn’t much more than that.

You want to click current, then dsl-4.4.10.iso, as stated in the readme.